# Mehrere Tätigkeiten aufzählen – groß- oder kleinschreiben?

Tags: capitalization

Im Augenblick sind meine Frau und ich uneins, ob "Musizieren" in folgendem Satz groß- oder kleingeschrieben werden muss. Aus meiner Sicht ist es ein Nomen und daher großzuschreiben.

Der Satz:

> Lesen und Musizieren machen einen großen Teil meiner Freizeit aus.

Oder ist korrekt:

> Lesen und musizieren machen einen großen Teil meiner Freizeit aus.

Besonders weil die neue deutsche Rechtschreibung alles unklar macht für Gehirne wie meins, traue ich mich das hier zu fragen. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Im Beispielsatz sind die Wörter *"Lesen"* und *"Musizieren"* Substantive (Nomen) und das Subjekt des Satzes. Das heißt, sie müssen in jedem Fall **großgeschrieben** werden.

Man kann auf einfache Weise prüfen, ob die Wörter Substantive sind, indem man versucht, Artikel davorzustellen:

> *Das* Lesen und *das* Musizieren machen einen großen Teil meiner Freizeit aus.

Wären die Wörter Verben, dann müsste man *musizieren* natürlich kleinschreiben wie im folgenden Beispiel:

> Lesen und musizieren wir doch heute!

Comment: Seh ich genauso. Hehe. Danke. Warum traut meine Frau Dir mir als mir? :-)